# how do I terminate data sent by java socket to python?

Tags: java, python, sockets

server side python:

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 18404))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
print conn.recv(100)
s.close()
```

client side java:

```
Socket client=new Socket("localhost",18404);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
out.print("hi1");
out.print("hi2");
out.close();
```

---

the output I get from print conn.recv(100) is "hi1hi2"
My question is, how do I terminate the output sent by the first out.print("hi1"); so it only receives "hi1".
I tried `out.print("hi1\r");` when I did that it only received hi2.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it no doubt received the whole string `'hi1\rhi2'`.  You `print`ed that, and only saw the `hi2` part because the carriage return made the last 3 characters overwrite (on screen) the first 3.

Just add a split

```
a, b = conn.recv(100).split('\r')
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: you are right, thank you I am less confused now.
but do you know if there is any other way to just take one string and stop receiving?

Comment: @user3571278, not any way that's both reliable and practical performance wise, with TCP, which is a **stream** protocol - just one octet after the other; you **could** hack some protocol on top of it but that requires both sender and receiver to follow the other protocol and is really a separate Q (which I'd encourage you to open **with** full explanation of *why* you think you need such functionality).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
out.print("hi1\n");
```

Comment: I tried that it still takes the 2 strings "hi1\n" and "hi\2"